# How to create button filter in django, without reloading the page?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am getting a list containing books, I have to make filter button to categorise it, Right now I am passing argument in the link "**?filter=2**" with each button click. But this requires reloading the page.

```
    In the get function 
    self.book_type = request.GET.get("book_type")

    in the get_queryset
    return qs.filter(book_filter=self.book_type)

    HTML
    Simply redirecting to the page with a query added to the link 
    containing ?book_type=" anything"
```

Comment: Everything that should work without reloading has to be implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: Should I pass the book category as a number or string, in the HTML and then filter using javascript or ajax?

Comment: Please provide a code which you have tried for this

Answer (score 0):

you have to had a view like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_books(request):
    book_type = request.GET.get("book_type")
    res = qs.filter(book_filter=self.book_type)
    return JsonResponse({"data": res})
```

Then create url in your template like this(it creates a javascript varibale contains url to get_books):

```
<script> book_get_url = "{% url 'route_name_to_get_books_from_urls.py' %}";</script>
```

now you can use the `book_get_url` variable in your javascript like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: book_get_url,
    type: "GET",
    "data": {
         book_type: here is your book_type as a number
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //here you have your books in `data.data` in json fromat
    }
)};
```